# jQuery compatibility issue with select list options

Tags: jquery, html

Using jQuery 3.3.1:

[image]

Using jQuery 1.12.2:

[image]

I have a select list with multiple options. I'm using jQuery to assign these options to an array, `categories`. When I use jQuery version 1.12.2, my array has the correct length. Upgrading to jQuery version 3.3.1, this seems to break and `categories` has a length of 0. Does anyone have a way of fixing this in jQuery version 3? Above, image1 shows the results with version 3. image2 shows the results of version 1.

HTML:

```
<select id="category" size="2">
    <option value="0">All</option>
    <option value="1">Option A</option>
    <option value="2">Option B</option>
    <option value="3">Option C</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
var categories = $("#category option");
// categories.length is 4 with jQuery version 1.12
// categories.length is 0 with jQuery version 3.3
```

Comment: `categories` is not an array, it's a jQuery object.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, do you know why the object is behaving differently depending on the version?

Comment: It shouldn't work differently. You need to post the code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Works as expected here: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/yxp5e9fa/1/

Comment: If you were to just look at the categories object, is it empty?

Comment: Look at it how, in the console?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yxp5e9fa/4/

Comment: Converting an object to a string returns `[object Object]`. What were you expecting instead.

Comment: See the images I've added above, this is the difference I'm experiencing.

Comment: Is your code inside `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: Yes, there is no difference anywhere besides  the jQuery version.

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. We can't reproduce it, so you must be doing something different.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the help. There's not much else I can provide.

Comment: You haven't provided anything. One line of code is hardly a MCVE.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to write `.length`. Dont know about jquery 1.12 but at latest you should put `.length` to get the length of an array.

**[Here](http://cr8code.co/editor.php?workid=20c490d2ce7a05099011c0d8ec72be79)** is working demo

Comment: I think he just didn't show this, since he says he gets length 4 in 1.12.

Comment: The length specifically isn't the issue, it's the difference between version 1 and 3 is causing problems on the `categories` object in my code.

Comment: My code here uses jquery 3.1 and as you see it works.@noclist